# OpenCV mask unwanted peaks

Tags: opencv, mask

I have a problem with the contour, i.e. the mask I get after that. I am bothered by all the peaks, I marked them with a red circle, which remain after the graph. Is there any easy way to get rid of them?

[image: Mask]

```
h, w = img.shape[:2]
mask = np.zeros((h, w), np.uint8)

# Transform to gray colorspace and threshold the image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Search for contours and select the biggest one and draw it on mask
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cntsSorted = sorted(contours, key=lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x), reverse=True)

for n in range(0,2):
    cnt = cntsSorted[n]
    cv2.drawContours(mask, [cnt], 0, 255, -1)

    # Perform a bitwise operation
    color = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    crop = color[y:(y + h)-3, x+3:x + w]
```

Comment: An erode operstion with an appropriate kernel should work.

Comment: I will try, tnx!